# difference between ODBCINI and ODBCINSTINI

Tags: odbc

The DSN is specified in both the files(`ODBCINI` and `ODBCINSTINI`).

And we can use `SQLConnect` or `SQLDriverConnect` in both the cases.
Can someone with practical experience help me in distinguishing between the two?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/619050/looking-for-good-documentation-of-odbc-ini-and-odbcinst-ini-files-on-linux has a good overview of what should be in each file - you should have the DSN details in odbc.ini and the driver details in odbcinst.ini

Comment: but DSN itself can have the driver details. It worked at my end.

Comment: Driver managers may allow driver details in the DSN (see http://www.unixodbc.org/odbcinst.html for information on why historically this was supported as e.g. a workaround for permission issues), but references including that one and the serverfault link mentioned earlier show driver-specific information (including path) going in odbcinst.ini, and DSN-specific information (including server and port) going in odbc.ini, which does seem a more logical approach.

Comment: Ok, so i should interpret that in DSN(inside ODBCINI) we don't have to mention a full driver path. Full driver related information should persist in ODBCINSTINI

Am i write?

Comment: Yes, that would be a normal way to proceed.

Comment: you could have mentioned the same thing as an answer :)